# strange results on composing verbs in J

Tags: j

I am wondering why the following failed to work.

```
   (1=$:@([:+/[:*:@"."0":)`]@.(e.&1 4))7
1
```

and

```
   (({&('no';'yes'))@(1=$:@([:+/[:*:@"."0":)`]@.(e.&1 4)))7
┌──┐
│no│
└──┘
```

I would expect it to return `yes` since it is taking the second argument (because the first expression evaluates to `1`). Could anybody please explain?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I must admit that it is difficult to figure out what you are trying to do, but the issue i think is your use of Self-Reference ($:).

The description of Self-Reference in the J dictionary states '$: denotes the longest verb that contains it.'  http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d212.htm

By combining 
    `({&('no';'yes'))` with your original verb

```
(1=$:@([:+/[:*:@"."0":)`]@.(e.&1 4))
```

You have actually changed the verb that $: self references and I believe this results in the (unexpected) behaviour. I hope that this helps. If you can give a reason for using $: I might be able to give a better answer as to why your verb works this way. I tend to use it very little, as there are usually better solutions in J.

Just another thought.  You could define the parts of the verb you are looking to create separately and this would limit the scope of the $: and give you the behaviour that you would like.

```
   choose=: (1=$:@([:+/[:*:@"."0":)`]@.(e.&1 4))
   display=:({&('no';'yes'))
   display @ choose 7
┌───┐
│yes│
└───┘
```

Comment: could you please explain why `(({&('no';'yes'))@(1=$:@([:+/[:*:@"."0":)`]@.(e.&1 4)))7` would result in `no`? What does `$:` reference now and how the result is computed?

Comment: Might be best to look at the link to the dictionary for $: http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d212.htm   It basically takes the largest verb that it is part of and puts that in its place. It is the recursion primitive in J. The dictionary has some good examples of how it used to simulate the factorial primitive.

Comment: Thank you bob. But still, is there any easy way to tell which verb does `$:` represent exactly? In a complex tacit form, how to tell that, because in boxed form, it is a giant verb any way, right?

Comment: Well, at the end of my answer you see choose defined and in fact that is what $: stands for each time it is called. The longest verb it is defined in is what it represents. So at the point that you call $: , you are actually calling choose one more time  When you extended the verb by adding what I called the display verb, you made your verb much longer and now it was returning boxed yes's and no's. What is it that you are trying to do by using $: That may help me know what you are missing about how $: works.